# Use resources in jar

Tags: java, android, jar

How can I use drawables from within a jar file?

**What I tried, and as I understand**:

1. I cannot use `Library Project` http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects because the library would compiles with the application that uses it. I dynamically load that jar library so this shouldn't work.
2. I could use `Picture Style` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html. But then I need to create a bitmap from the res directory in my library. Is it possible?
3. I know I could do it using dynamic loading of the resources. I rather not use dynamic loading again (this jar is also dynamically loaded)

**More info**
I have a jar file that is *dynamically loaded* from a system service and I would like that all the code of the system service will be in that jar.

I would like to present notifications in the system service and for that I need to use a drawable from within the jar. 
I would like to have a res directory, like every application has and be able to use the png in it for the notifications.

Every help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use drawables from within a jar file?

There are no drawable resources in a JAR file. There may be image files in the JAR, which you can try to load using `BitmapFactory`. Resources, of any type, are **only** compiled into the APK file.

> I dynamically load that jar library

That is dangerous from a security standpoint, unless you can guarantee that nobody can replace that JAR file from wherever you retrieve it.

> But then I need to create a bitmap from the res directory in my library. Is it possible?

You can perhaps load files out of your JAR and parse them as bitmaps using `BitmapFactory`, which you could then use with notification-related methods that take a `Bitmap` object, like those on `Notification.BigPictureStyle`.

> I have a jar file that is dynamically loaded from a system service

Unless you are creating your own build of Android rolled into your own ROM mod, you are not creating a "system service".

> I would like to have a res directory, like every application has and be able to use the png in it for the notifications.

Then do not dynamically load the JAR, but instead include the code (and resources) in your application project.

In short, JARs have nothing whatsoever to do with Android resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I have my own build of android and I'm creating a system service. I have to dynamically load it because the jar is not in the android framework but in another partition.
If I have the jar and a res directory in it, do you happen to know how to load it as a bitmap? 
A sample code, or reference to sample code would be great

Comment: @RavitD: "I have to dynamically load it because the jar is not in the android framework but in another partition" -- and if that partition is writeable, this is a serious security hole.

Comment: @RavitD: "If I have the jar and a res directory in it, do you happen to know how to load it as a bitmap?" -- I would assume that you [use `JarFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) to get an `InputStream` on the image entry in the file, then use `BitmapFactory` to decode the image to a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Do I still need the `JarFile` if I'm trying to reference the res directory from within the my jar?

Comment: @RavitD: You can try `getResourceAsStream()` on some `Class` that is that JAR, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Had the issue whilst developing an ant - task for automated GUI generation in Android.
getResourcesAsStream (@CommonsWare) is a good hint, though I think it should not be applied to one of the classes but to the system's class loader. E.g.:

ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
   String yourPathToFileInJar = "/the/package/in/jar/fileInjar";
   InputStream url = loader.getResourceAsStream(yourPathToFileInJar);

And please (not to @CommonsWare) avoid answers like : Don't do it when someone is asking a question specially when its common practices in the Java - World.

Comment: I'm having a hard time referencing the png file.
I put it in src/my/package/pen.png and getResourcesAsStream keeps returning null. 
I fear the pgn file is not in the jar. I'm using an Android.mk file do you happen to know if I need to explicitly include that png file?
Also, when opening the jar with eclipse and tar tv - I couldn't see anything but classes.dex and some manifest file